# asp Automatic copy or download of database file from online to local pc

Tags: copy, backup

I want to make automatic copy or download of database file from online to my local pc
in a folder created and names by date.
if its done I will run this asp file everyday using windows task scheduler to make a backup.
I write this code it work in localhost.

```
<%
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Folder = "d:\db_backup" & "\"
iss_no=(FormatDateTime(date,1))
objFSO.CreateFolder (Folder&iss_no)
objFSO.CopyFile "http://mywebsite.com/database/contracts.accdb", (Folder&iss_no) &"\"& "trust.accdb"
%>
```